# How to represent/visualize data pairs in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I have a list of objects. Each object has a dictionary as one of its attributes:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> testArguments = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

When I launch my application it iterates over this list of objects and shows object names in a `checkedListBox`. What I want to achieve is the following:

- When I choose(click) an object name on the list, I want to get and show a list of its `testArguments` pairs.
- I want the values (not the keys) of these pairs to be editable. On a later stage I want to use serialization to enable save/load of these values.

After some research I found the `DataGridView` Class that allegedly should be able to help me with the above. However I fail to reach the desired result. Moreover, according to what I read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d3698481-0b48-4b09-8652-5bfa35a13585/datagridview-bound-to-a-generic-dictionary?forum=winformsdatacontrols), it doesn't seem possible. Is that so? And if yes, what is the best approach to something like that?

**P.S.** Just to emphasize, I am not asking specifically how to make `DataGridView` work in that case. I am looking for any general solution to visually display/represent a dictionary-like data structure. It does not even have to be a proper `Dictionary`. Any approach that will provide a solution is accepted.

Comment: Please define "editable". Modifying the value of a key-value pair seems reasonably straightforward since dictionary keys must be unique. But what behavior do you want, exactly, if the key is modified? Should the old key-value pair be replaced? Do you want to add a new key-value pair, keeping the old pair as well? Something else?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi. Sorry for not being clear on this one. I meant only the values, not the keys. I changed that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is that the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is not bindable. It doesn't implement the interfaces needed for proper binding, and for good reason: it's an inherently unordered collection, and the UI controls that use binding generally assume an ordered collection.

That said, you can still use `DataGridView` if you want. You'll just have to do things manually:

1. Populate the `DataGridView` control by enumerating your dictionary, and using one of the `Add()` method overloads on the `Rows` property of the `DataGridView` object.
2. Set the `ReadOnly` property to `true` for the column containing the keys, so that the user can edit only the values.
3. Handle the `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` event to receive notification that the user has edited a cell. When the event is raised, handle as appropriate (e.g. copy the value back to your dictionary object, updating any other views of the data as necessary, etc.).

Presumably you would also set the `AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` properties to `false`. Adding rows in particular would be tricky, because if you set the key column to read-only, the user won't be able to enter a key value for a new row. So you might as well not allow that at all.

You may also want to go ahead and order the dictionary data while adding it to the `DataGridView`, e.g. based on the key value, so the user can navigate the data more easily.

You could get fancy and try to wrap the dictionary object in some bindable implementation. E.g. wrap it in an `IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, and then pass that to `BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, or actually implement the whole `IBindingList` interface yourself. But doing so will probably involve dealing with a number of headaches, again most having to do with the fact that the dictionary itself is unordered, and so writing a bindable shim would involve imposing and maintaining some kind of order.

On the one hand, implementing `IList<T>` is simpler than implementing `IBindingList`. But on the other hand, implementing `IBindingList` gives you more control over the exact behavior and view of the dictionary. Either way, it would be painful. Dealing with the `DataGridView` directly is probably easier.

**Addendum:**
For what it's worth, here's a simple example of what a plain-vanilla, manually-bound implementation might look like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Form1(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dictionary = dictionary;
        _UpdateDictionaryView();
    }

    private void _UpdateDictionaryView()
    {
        _UpdateDictionaryListView();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(_dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp =>
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

            row.CreateCells(dataGridView1, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            return row;
        }).ToArray());

    }

    private void _UpdateDictionaryListView()
    {
        listBoxDictionaryView.Items.Clear();
        listBoxDictionaryView.Items.AddRange(
            _dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                        .Select(kvp => string.Format("Key: \"{0}\"; Value: \"{1}\"", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))
                        .ToArray());
    }

    private void buttonAddKeyValuePair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(tboxKey.Text, tboxValue.Text);
        _UpdateDictionaryView();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        _dictionary[(string)row.Cells[0].Value] = (string)row.Cells[1].Value;
        _UpdateDictionaryView();
        _SaveDictionaryData();
    }
}
```

*Form1.Designer.cs:* (for convenience)

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tboxValue = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.tboxKey = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.listBoxDictionaryView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.Key = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Value = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 25);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 17);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Key:";
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.buttonAddKeyValuePair);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.tboxValue);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.tboxKey);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 113);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "New key-value pair";
        // 
        // buttonAddKeyValuePair
        // 
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 78);
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.Name = "buttonAddKeyValuePair";
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.TabIndex = 2;
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.Text = "Add";
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonAddKeyValuePair.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAddKeyValuePair_Click);
        // 
        // tboxValue
        // 
        this.tboxValue.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 50);
        this.tboxValue.Name = "tboxValue";
        this.tboxValue.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
        this.tboxValue.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // tboxKey
        // 
        this.tboxKey.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(68, 22);
        this.tboxKey.Name = "tboxKey";
        this.tboxKey.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
        this.tboxKey.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 53);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 17);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label2.Text = "Value:";
        // 
        // listBoxDictionaryView
        // 
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.ItemHeight = 16;
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 133);
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.Name = "listBoxDictionaryView";
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 180);
        this.listBoxDictionaryView.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Key,
        this.Value});
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(201, 10);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(382, 303);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        // 
        // Key
        // 
        this.Key.HeaderText = "Key";
        this.Key.Name = "Key";
        this.Key.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // Value
        // 
        this.Value.HeaderText = "Value";
        this.Value.Name = "Value";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(595, 327);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBoxDictionaryView);
        this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonAddKeyValuePair;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tboxValue;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tboxKey;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBoxDictionaryView;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Key;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Value;
}
```

That follows essentially the exact template I proposed above. Note that the code rebuilds the views (`ListBox` and `DataGridView` both) from scratch on any change. For a relatively small number of dictionary entries (say up to hundreds or so), I think this should be fine. If you need to support more than that, you'll probably want to implement the view updates more efficiently.

For grins, I also tried wrapping the dictionary in an `IList<T>` implementation, which I then passed to `BindingSource<T>`, to be used as the `DataSource` for the view, arbitrarily imposing an order on the dictionary by maintaining a parallel list. If someone really needed a generalized solution, I could see how that approach might wind up being useful. But in this particular example, it was a lot of extra code as compared to the above and didn't really provide anything in the way of addition functionality.

I only implemented `IList<T>`, but I suppose if someone really wanted that generalized solution, it might be worth the time and effort to go ahead and implement `IBindingList`. That would give you a lot more control over the exact binding behaviors, and might wind up (a little) less hacky than my `IList<T>`/`BindingSource<T>`-based approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great and detailed answer. It will probably take me a while to go through it but I think I get the general idea of what's happening now. BTW, if you think there is another, maybe more proper solution to that problem, I will be happy to know. `DataGridView` was the only option I found but that might be just my lack of experience in C# and .NET in general. Thanks again!

Comment: @EugeneS: in Winforms, I think `DataGridView` is probably the best choice; it's the only built-in control that understands a tabular, editable format. WPF offers more flexibility in terms of composing UI, but you'd still run into the basic issue that a dictionary is unordered and unbindable, so you'd still have to write some sort of intermediary code to connect the dictionary to the UI.

Comment: @EugeneS: please see the added code example, in case it's useful in your deliberations. :)